# How can I add asterisks for the significant p-values in ggplot?

Tags: r

I want to show the significant values in the ggplot graph(please see the inputs as df1 and the expected output, graph). If the value is less than 0.001 I want to add ( "***"), if the p_value is less than 0.01 I want to add (**) and finally, if the p-value is less than 0.05 (*). I did it manually, but  how can I automatically  obtain such a graph which is represented below?

```
df1<-data.frame(size=c(1000,1500,2000,2500,
                   1000,1500,2000,2500), 
            difference=c(2.1622,2.4114,2.3592,2.4803,
                         1.5610,1.2705,1.4167,1.3223), 
            Gender=c("M","M","M","M", "F", "F","F","F"),
            p_val=c(0.0003, 0.6500, 1,0.02,0.0400,
                    0.3301,0.100,0.023))


ggplot(df1,  aes(x=size, y=difference, group=Gender )) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Gender))+   
  geom_point(aes(color=Gender))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#CC0000"))
```

[image: expected graph output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a column to your data with the desired label and use `geom_text()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(
        label = case_when(
            p_val > 0.05 ~ "",
            p_val > 0.01 ~ "*",
            p_val > 0.001 ~ "**",
            !is.na(p_val) ~ "***",
            TRUE ~ NA_character_
        )
    )

ggplot(df1,  aes(x=size, y=difference, group=Gender )) +
    geom_line(aes(color=Gender))+   
    geom_point(aes(color=Gender))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#CC0000")) +
    geom_text(aes(label = label), nudge_y = 0.05)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  Tried to avoid adding any dependencies, but typically I'd say you would use `dplyr::case_when`

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

df1<-data.frame(size=c(1000,1500,2000,2500,
                       1000,1500,2000,2500), 
                difference=c(2.1622,2.4114,2.3592,2.4803,
                             1.5610,1.2705,1.4167,1.3223), 
                Gender=c("M","M","M","M", "F", "F","F","F"),
                p_val=c(0.0003, 0.6500, 1,0.02,0.0400,
                        0.3301,0.100,0.023))



df1$p_val_sig <- c("***", "**", "*", "")[findInterval(df1$p_val, c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05)) + 1]

ggplot(df1,  aes(x=size, y=difference, group=Gender )) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Gender))+   
  geom_point(aes(color=Gender)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = p_val_sig), vjust = -1) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#CC0000"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `base R` solution to create a new column with labels:

```
df1<-data.frame(size=c(1000,1500,2000,2500,
                       1000,1500,2000,2500), 
                difference=c(2.1622,2.4114,2.3592,2.4803,
                             1.5610,1.2705,1.4167,1.3223), 
                Gender=c("M","M","M","M", "F", "F","F","F"),
                p_val=c(0.0003, 0.6500, 1,0.02,0.0400,
                        0.3301,0.100,0.023))

#Create label
df1$Label <- NA
df1$Label[df1$p_val<0.001]<-'***'
df1$Label[df1$p_val<0.01 & is.na(df1$Label)]<-'**'
df1$Label[df1$p_val<0.05 & is.na(df1$Label)]<-'*'

ggplot(df1,  aes(x=size, y=difference, group=Gender,label=Label)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(0.9),vjust=-0.5)+
  geom_line(aes(color=Gender))+   
  geom_point(aes(color=Gender))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#CC0000"))
```

[image]